# Best approach for generating a non-predictable random ID?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to generate some sort of id, without using the `AUTO INCREMENT` since I don't want people to be able make a small script and look through the whole database. How would I generate such IDs making sure they are unique and easy to query?

Im using SQLite and nodeJS, although I plan on switching to something more robust in the future.

Comment: Add a module that supports UUIDs and use those.

Answer (score 2):

Use a normal `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column, but don't use `AUTOINCREMENT` (Which you usually don't want to use anyways). Then insert a row with a rowid of 9223372036854775807, the largest possible one. Further insertions without a rowid given will pick a random unused one. [Details](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE ex(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, x);
INSERT INTO ex VALUES (9223372036854775807, null);
INSERT INTO ex(x) VALUES ('foo');  -- uses a random id
SELECT last_insert_rowid();
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has these functions ([List](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#random)):

- `random`
- `randomblob`

So you could for example generate a GUID like this using SQLite but this is ugly ;-)

(unlikely that the same value would come out twice buyt add a UNIQUE constraint to be safe)

```
SELECT SUBSTR(UPPER(HEX(RANDOMBLOB(16))), 1, 8) || '-' ||
SUBSTR(UPPER(HEX(RANDOMBLOB(16))), 9, 4) || '-' ||
SUBSTR(UPPER(HEX(RANDOMBLOB(16))), 13, 4) || '-' ||
SUBSTR(UPPER(HEX(RANDOMBLOB(16))), 17, 4) || '-' ||
SUBSTR(UPPER(HEX(RANDOMBLOB(16))), 21, 12) AS guid
```

Example: `3326836A-881A-25D0-234F-F64A04EBD990`